# Wired Connection Fails, but WIFI is fine

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, networkmanager

Installed Debian yesterday and have had a pleasant experience except for my inability to get the Wired Connection working. I have a Wireless connection that connects and allows me to access Internet. The Wired connection activates, but does not have any Internet. I installed network-manager in hopes that it would do something.

> ip a (when I am connected to both wireless and wired)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:a0:50:88:02:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2601:410:4200:1490:3db7:b480:c149:bae3/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 212562sec preferred_lft 85850sec
    inet6 2601:410:4200:1490:56a0:50ff:fe88:267/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 212562sec preferred_lft 212562sec
    inet6 fe80::56a0:50ff:fe88:267/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:85:de:cb:f4:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.19/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
       valid_lft 85510sec preferred_lft 85510sec
    inet6 2601:410:4200:1490:ae2d:d92b:d52e:bc36/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic 
       valid_lft 212562sec preferred_lft 212562sec
    inet6 fe80::750d:dee3:cc5c:1169/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Noticed that the eno1 is missing an IPv4 address.

Also tried tweaking files in

> /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

> cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
>       auto lo
>       iface lo inet loopback

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

One thing that I noticed so far is that my Ethernet is called eth0 in interfaces.d, while it's called eno1 from ip a. I tried to update the etho0 to eno1 and then restart the service, but was not successful. From my understanding of network-manager, the interfaces file should be ignored now?

> cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you try changing `eth0` to `eno1`? this may be the main issue, as it seems the system interface name is different than the one you try to set.

Comment: @Bart , when I did that I got a new connection called Ifupdown (eno1), which activates but still fails to connect to Internet :(

Comment: During troubleshoot, you should temporarily disable the wireless interface to avoid any possible interaction. You can run a manual dhcp command. Assuming you have isc-dhcp-client, you should run `dhclient -v eno1` and observe the results. You're supposed to see DHCPDISCOVER then DHCPOFFER then DHCPREQUEST then DHCPACK . Anyway you should add the results on your question.